# Having trouble converting mysql_result vars to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

after searching a bit I've found posts in the same vein, but nothing thats specifically helpful to my problem.

I'm slogging through my code updating mysql to mysqli, and I'm hitting a snag on dumping search results into vars.
With a while loop I process each row and dump the fields into vars for display, then repeat until the resulting rows have all been displayed (basic search engine results)

My original code has the following var types (I'll show one for convenience)

```
$title = mysql_result($rs,$i,"title");
```

"rs" is the con and query, i is the row number, "title" is the field name

I see there are a few methods in the manual and mysqli_data_seek seems to be the correct route here, but I'm blowing it on parameters according to my editor (call uses 2 parameters and I'm using 3)

```
$title = mysqli_data_seek($rs,$i,"title");
```

I have 18 of these vars in the while loop, how can I make this work correctly? (procedural style)

Comment: First of all, if you have 18 of these you are probably doing something wrong. Secondly, we need more code to actually see what is happening here

Comment: If you have the time to convert it to `mysqli_`, then do yourself a favor and instead convert it into `PDO`. `mysql_` and `mysqli_` make things complicated for no reason.

Comment: I also agree with @Mikey PDO is way easier than `mysql*_*`

Comment: Mysqli might be a few more lines to work with, but there's nothing *wrong* with it, as long as you parameterize your queries. If you like pdo better, by all means! But at least try both and see which one is most comfortable and suitable for your needs.

Comment: well its old code using mysql, and I'd rather not have to rewrite it to the PDO if I can avoid it, I'm just trying to make it run under php7. A real rewrite will be on the horizon, but I'm not a coder by profession so I need a more immediate solution. And Grumpy, yes its bloated, but its not used enough for any appreciable impact on the server (less than 20 visitors a day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method as `mysql_result` within the MySQLi-library. So you have to do it with one of the alternatives. Either run

```
$allData = mysqli_fetch_all($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Has to be run only once for the result!
// And access data via
$title = $allData[ $i /* row-number */ ]['title'];
// Or (you didn't provide your current loop)
foreach($allData as $i => $row) {
    $title = $row['title'];
}
```

Or run

```
mysqli_data_seek($rs, $i); // Set pointer in mysqli to row-nr $i
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$title = $row['title'];
```

Or run (most preferable solution I guess, but you didn't provide your current loop):

```
// Loop over all rows in the result-set
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
}
```